# Measure time metric is above threshold

Tags: prometheus

I have a metric for my Minecraft server, `mc_player_online`. It shows `1` if a player is online, or `0` otherwise.

I can graph it to show how many players have been online.

[image: Graph showing player count over the course of 2 days]

I want to calculate the play time of a player on the Minecraft server. The output could be tabulated to show "Player Steve's Playtime = 2d 3h 45m".

How can I calculate how long a player is online for?

I'd also like to calculate the utilisation of the server. So if the server is running from 12:00 to 13:00, and 10 players log on simultaneously at 12:00 and play until 12:10, then the utilisation should be 10 minutes (not 10 * 10 minutes).

How can I calculate how long a metric (`mc_player_online`) is above a threshold (0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael for their answer. It pointed me in the right direction. It has an issue where the range vector was incorrectly multiplied.

TL;DR: Here's the fixed version

```
sum_over_time((sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0)[1h:1s])
```

I'll try and break it down...

1. Get the total a metric is above zero, and use `bool` make it either 1 or 0

   ```
   sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0
   ```
2. Use a [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) to break that down by hour, with a 1 second resolution

   ```
   (sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0)[1h:1s]
   ```

   The result is a range vector that is counts, per hour, the number of seconds a player is online.
3. Finally, use an '[aggregation over time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time)' function to sum the range vector into a single number.

   ```
   sum_over_time((sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0)[1h:1s])
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I assume `mc_player_online` is a metric per player (with the name of the player as a label).

A little precision: the graph you showed only indicates when a player is online. If you want to see the number of players at any one time, the expression would be:

```
sum(mc_player_online)
```

To calculate the time a player spends on Minicraft, you can only do so on a sliding window expressed  as the last `N <unit of time>` (last 7 days, 1 month ...). Taking as an example the time played over the last week in seconds (7 days is 604800s), it would be:

```
avg_over_time(mc_player_online[7d]) * 604800
```

You can have a nice display using a table display in Grafana. If you want to accumulate from forever, you'll have to have a [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) and let Prometheus do the recording.

The computation of the utilization is similar to the computation of the time spent by a user but with an expression evaluating to 1 when at least one user is online (using the `bool` modifier):

```
sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0
```

This become (over the last hour):

```
avg_over_time((sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0)[1h:]) * 86400
```

Note that this expression requires Prometheus version which supports [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) (`version >= 2.7`). If your Prometheus is older, you can make do with recording rules.

Comment: Thanks, this is all great, except for one problem I've encountered. If a player joins, then their range-vector will exist for less time than other players. E.g. if they joined 1 day ago, then their range-vector is correctly calculated across 1 hour, but it's then multiplied by 7 days, so their play time is shown as 7 days. To solve this their range-vector needs a default value of 0 when it doesn't exist. Can this be done?

Comment: Okay, fixed it! `avg_over_time(mc_player_online[7d]) * count_over_time(mc_player_online[7d:1s]) ` returns the time played in seconds. Could you update your answer and I'll accept it? :)

Comment: Actually that can be simplified further, since it's calculating `(sum / count) * count`. So just do `sum_over_time(mc_player_online[7d:1s])` returns seconds played over 7 days, no need for multiplying by seconds.

Comment: The total utilisation can be simplified to `sum_over_time((sum(mc_player_online) > bool 0)[1h:1s])`